# onDargStart eventlistener outputs null values in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am trying to set up drag and drop feature using React. But the "event" outputs "null" values in "onDragStart" listener.

```
dragStart(event) { 
    // here events outputs null values for different fields
    console.log(event); // NULL VALUES

    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', event.target.id);
  }

render(){
    return(
        <div onDragStart={(event) => this.dragStart(event)} draggable="true" id="dragtarget" className="sticker">
          // some JSX
        </div>

      )
  }
```

Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event` is a nullified object in React. You can find more about events in React in their [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) documentation.

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of SyntheticEvent, a cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. It has the same interface as the browser’s native event, including stopPropagation() and preventDefault(), except the events work identically across all browsers.
>
> If you find that you need the underlying browser event for some reason, simply use the nativeEvent attribute to get it. Every SyntheticEvent object has the following attributes:

In their code example they note that `event` is nullified.

```
function onClick(event) {
  console.log(event); // => nullified object.
  console.log(event.type); // => "click"
  const eventType = event.type; // => "click"

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(event.type); // => null
    console.log(eventType); // => "click"
  }, 0);

  // Won't work. this.state.clickEvent will only contain null values.
  this.setState({clickEvent: event});

  // You can still export event properties.
  this.setState({eventType: event.type});
}
```

Comment: This idea helped. 
Another ques: What is react event value names for js startX/startY mouse events??

Comment: @HarshK `event.clientX` and event.clientY` will give you the mouse coordinates at the time of the event. This will obviously only happen once in a `onDragStart` callback, and if used in `onDrag` you may want to throttle or debounce the callback.